# To async, or not to async in node.js?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, asynchronous, express, mongoose

I'm still learning the node.js ropes and am just trying to get my head around what I should be deferring, and what I should just be executing.

I know there are other questions relating to this subject generally, but I'm afraid without a more relatable example I'm struggling to 'get it'.

My general understanding is that if the code being executed is non-trivial, then it's probably a good idea to async it, as to avoid it holding up someone else's session. There's clearly more to it than that, and callbacks get mentioned a lot, and I'm not 100% on why you wouldn't just synch everything. I've got some ways to go.

So here's some basic code I've put together in an express.js app:

```
app.get('/directory', function(req, res) {
        process.nextTick(function() {
            Item.
                find().
                sort( 'date-modified' ).
                exec( function ( err, items ){
                    if ( err ) {
                        return next( err );
                    }
                    res.render('directory.ejs', {
                        items : items
                    });
                });
        });
    });
```

Am I right to be using `process.nextTick()` here? My reasoning is that as it's a database call then some actual work is having to be done, and it's the kind of thing that could slow down active sessions. Or is that wrong?

Secondly, I have a feeling that if I'm deferring the database query then it should be in a callback, and I should have the actual page rendering happening synchronously, on condition of receiving the callback response. I'm only assuming this because it seems like a more common format from some of the examples I've seen - if it's a correct assumption can anyone explain *why* that's the case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are using it wrong in this case, because `.exec()` is already asynchronous (You can tell by the fact that is accepts a callback as a parameter).

To be fair, most of what needs to be asynchronous in nodejs already is.

As for page rendering, if you require the results from the database to render the page, and those arrive asynchronously, you can't really render the page synchronously.

Comment: Oh god now I just have more questions! Incidentally when you say that it accepts a callback, do you just mean that you can put a function in it (and thereby `return` something)? Or do I also not totally get callbacks? With regards to the page rendering that's what I didn't get. So although I *could* abstract the database call away for re-use, there's nothing wrong with this structure?

Comment: There are a few approaches to how to write asynchronous code. The lowest form (which nodejs uses by default) is the concept of callbacks. You perform an action 
(like `.exec()`) and pass a function to be called back (hence, callback) when the data is available. The action returns *immediately*, and the rest of the execution continues. At some point in the future, the action actually finishes, and the callback is called, often with 2 parameters: `error` and `data`. Where `error` would be null or undefined if everything completed succesfully.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking it's best practice to make everything you can asynchronous rather than relying on synchronous functions ... in most cases that would be something like `readFile` vs. `readFileSync`.  In your example, you're not doing anything synchronously with i/o.  The only synchronous code you have is the logic of your program (which requires CPU and thus has to be synchronous in node) but these are tiny little things by comparison.

I'm not sure what `Item` is, but if I had to guess what `.find().sort()` does is build a query string internally to the system.  It does not actually run the query (talk to the DB) until `.exec` is called.  `.exec` takes a callback, so it will communicate with the DB asynchronously.  When that communication is done, the callback is called.

Using `process.nextTick` does nothing in this case.  That would just delay the calling of its code until the next event loop which there is no need to do.  It has no effect on synchronicity or not.

I don't really understand your second question, but if the rendering of the page depends on the result of the query, you have to defer rendering of the page until the query completes -- you are doing this by rendering in the callback.  The rendering itself `res.render` may not be entirely synchronous either.  It depends on the internal mechanism of the library that defines the `render` function.

In your example, `next` is not defined.  Instead your code should probably look like:

```
app.get('/directory', function(req, res) {
    Item.
        find().
        sort( 'date-modified' ).
        exec(function (err, items) {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                res.status(500).end("Database error");
            }
            else {
                res.render('directory.ejs', {
                    items : items
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation - and the correction to the code is very helpful! I wanted to ask about the error block but was going to investigate that separately as to avoid a 'teach me node!' post :) What you've done makes sense to me though, importantly. I should have mentioned by the way that I'm using mongoose and mongodb - that's the mongoose query format.